# Display in alert window copied HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Professional Ditails</legend>
    <div id="initialTransInfoElement">
        <p>
            <label id="lblInstitution1">
                Institution
                <input type="text" name="inptInstitution" required="required" />
            </label>
            <label id="lblQualification1">
                Qualification
                <select name="cars">
                    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
                    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </p>
    </div>

    <button type="button" name="button" onclick="test()">
        test</button>
</fieldset>

<script type="text/javascript">
function toCelsius(fahrenheit) {
    alert("DDD");
}

function test() {
    var elem = $("#initialTransInfoElement").clone();
    alert(elem.toString());
}
```

When I click the button "test" I want to see the copied elementrs in alet window but instead I get alert window displsy this text:
**`[object Object]`**

What do I missing?Why I get the massage above?And how can I make the copied HTML code displayed?

Comment: Are you looking for elem[0].outerHTML?

Comment: This one?: http://jsfiddle.net/33kocbng/ | I also added `console.log` so you can remove the `alert`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to use:

```
alert(elem.html());
```

[Example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/G0IUf31Lj3asf0Yu6gyp?p=preview)

Comment: It's works,thanks but what is wrong with this row:
 "alert(elem.toString());" ?
You have any idea?

Comment: The default of toString() just spits out the object name. It's similar to how other languages like C# and Java work. The language has no idea what you want displayed. You could override the toString() function and have it return this.html() for instance. Unless you have a very good use for this, I don't recommend doing that.  Also, if this addresses your answer please mark as answer so other users can find the solution if they encounter the same issue.